# Match two columns and output in column next to column 1 from column next to column 2

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, match

Trying through this problem in VBA, I've checked a few of the threads here but whatever variant I try I seem to encounter errors I can't resolve.

Sheet 1 Col A has values to match with Sheet 2 Col A, and if matched then the value I want to return in Sheet 1 Col A is contained in Sheet 2 Col B (cell next to value in Col A).

The goal is to:

- Check Sheet1 Col A vs Sheet2 Col A for matches.
- If Match, output Sheet2 Col B (Sheet2 Col A Offset(0, 1)) to Sheet1 Col B ((Sheet1 Col A Offset(0, 1)).

And so basically to match Sheet1 Col A to Sheet2 Col A, output matched row values from Sheet2 Col B to Sheet1 Col B.

Current attempts (I appreciate there are errors contained, just trying to show logic):

```
'In this first one I'm trying to iterate through the rows to find the matches and then output offset 0,1 to offset 0,1

Sub loopMatch()

ReDim colA(1 To 22) As Variant
ReDim colB(1 To 27) As Variant

sheet1colA = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25").Value
sheet2colA = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A27").Value

Dim rowCounter1 As Integer
Dim rowCounter2 As Integer
Dim valueFound As Boolean
Dim valueLost As String
valueLost = "The following item(s) are unmatched: "

For rowCounter1 = LBound(sheet1colA) To UBound(sheet1colA)
    
    For rowCounter2 = LBound(sheet2colA) To UBound(sheet2colA)
        If sheet2colA(rowCounter2, 1) = sheet1colA(rowCounter1, 1) Then
            valueFound = True
            Worksheets("sheet1colA").Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet2colA").Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
        
    Next rowCounter2
        If valueFound = False Then
            valueLost = valueLost & sheet2colA(rowCounter1, 1) & "; "
        End If
    valueFound = False
    
Next rowCounter1
```

Also tried something like:

```
'This one is just a match search and attempt to output per offset

Sub LoopMatch1()

Dim match

match = Application.match(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25").Value, Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A27"), 0)

If Not IsError(match) Then
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25").Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A27" & match).Offset(0, 1).Value
Else
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25").Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Found"
End If
```

Anyone have a better idea of this? Quite new to VBA.

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? It looks like a simple `IF()`, `Match()` or `VLookup()` assignment.

Comment: Dominique beat me to it! Just add a column with a formua e.g. `=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),1),"")`

Comment: i'm just about to go out but your best bet is to do this in the Arrays, you're already going through them any way.  change `sheet2colA` to `sheet2colA = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:B27").Value` then instead of changing the values in the cells change the values in the array i.e. `If sheet2colA(rowCounter2, 1) = sheet1colA(rowCounter1, 1) Then` this:  `sheet1colA(rowCounter2, 1) = sheet1colA(rowCounter1, 2)` then put `sheet1colA` back in to the sheet right at the end `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25").Value = sheet1colA`

Comment: @CHill60 works if you want a new column but not if you want the values in the original column

Comment: As in IF Col 1A = Col 2A Then Col 1B = Col 2B? Like I say quite new to VBA, but I'm not sure how I'd do that even with regular formulas -- But if it can be done with a simple formula in a box, surely it can be simply implemented in VBA too?

Comment: @InjuredCoding Don't need values in original column, starts with 3 lists (2 match, 1 reference list) and goal is to output a new 4th list (as you say). Will give this one a try soon, cheers.

Comment: @InjuredCoding - the question stated "output matched row values from Sheet2 Col B to Sheet1 Col B.". If you want the stuff in the original column (which the OP does not) then set up the formula, calculate if necessary, assign the Value from B to A, remove content of B (or whereever the temporary column was put)

Comment: @User41824474 - "As in IF Col 1A = Col 2A Then Col 1B = Col 2B" - no, that will depend on matching data  being on the same row number - which won't be the case if there are blanks.

Comment: @CHill60 - Rather, this is to match Col 1A to Col2A then use Col2B as reference to populate (the empty) Col1B. --


For clarity, the values for Sheet 2 A B do correspond by row, this is essentially a dictionary translator function.

Comment: @User41824474 - which is how the formula I gave you works. Try it. Or @Dominique's suggestion of a Vlookup. Absolutely no need to wander through loops of cells or arrays - use the power of the tool itself and deal in sets `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25").Formula = IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),1),"")`

Comment: if the values correspond by row you could just use `=if(a1=sheet2!a1,sheet2!b1,"")` in vba you could change mine to have `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B3:B25").Value = sheet1colA` and you may want to blank out the rows that don't match.  agree with above though that there is not much need for VBA here

Comment: @InjuredCoding - No worries, appreciate the help - The issue I'm still struggling with is that I want to return the value of Sheet2ColA.Offset(0, 1) as that is the reference cell being translated by the match. However, this returns an error with that not being an object and I'm too new to VBA to be able to resolve/understand what's happening here even through my research.

Comment: so the comments made are far better than the code you have for the problem stated.  however, the issue you're having is that you can only offset a range.  i think this is probably the line you refer to `Worksheets("sheet1colA").Offset(0, 1).Value` you're referring to a sheet called `sheet1colA` which i doubt exists?  and you're offset that sheet not a cell in that sheet.

Comment: Maybe try to use the find method ? First, set your sheet1colA and sheet2colA as range .... example : `set sheet1colA = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A3:A25")`. Then loop to each cell in sheet1colA range variable and check if the value of the looped cell is found in sheet2colA range. `for each cell in sheet1colA` ... `if not sheet2colA.find(cell.value) is nothing then` .... `cell.offset(0,1).value = sheet2colA.find(cell.value).offset(0,1).value` ... `else` .... `msgbox "cell.value & " is not found in sheet2 col A"` .... `end if` ... `next`